# ServiceStack benchmark continued: why does persisting a simple (complex) to JSON slow down SELECTs?

Tags: c#, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I would like to switch over to OrmLite, and I need to figure out if it is slow, and if so, why.

In my research, I come to the conclusion that complex objects, that in OrmLite are blobbed to JSON, is the culprit of very slow SELECTs.

Therefore, I created a new project that focuses solely on OrmLite, and does not compare with anything else other than itself, and the aim here is to see the differences between having blobbed JSON objects, and not having them.

It can be found on GitHub:
https://github.com/tedekeroth/ormlitebenchmarking

Solution looks like this:

[image]

I am running OrmLite 5.1.1 on a Windows 7, 2.6Ghz, 24 GB RAM and no CPU load currently, using MySql 5.6. Application connects to 127.0.0.1 (root/root) and needs database "ormlite".

I have enabled ThrowOnError:

```
OrmLiteConfig.ThrowOnError = JsConfig.ThrowOnError = true;
```

The application looks like this:

[image]

No data: just the object created, no properties has data:

[image]

Primitives: Just some of the simple primitive properties are populated:

[image]

Prim + one complex: all primitives as above + one blobbed complex object:

[image]

Full data: all of the above + another 2 complex blobbed objects:

[image]

The **Create** button first creates 10 000 objects in a list, and then they are persisted using OrmLite Insert method. Time measurement is done only for the INSERTs, not creating the objects.

```c#
public void AddRow<T>(T coreObject) where T : CoreObject
{
    long id = 0;
    using (var _db = _dbFactory.Open())
    {
        id = _db.Insert<T>(coreObject, selectIdentity: true);
    }           
}
```

The **Read** button reads all rows in the table, and recreates the Customer objects:

```c#
public List<T> FetchAll<T>()
{
    using (var _db = _dbFactory.Open())
    {
        List<T> list = _db.Select<T>();
        return list;
    }
}
```

So, testing should be done like:

- Select mode, and press **Create**, time took will be displayed
- Press **Read** to read back all the rows currently in the table

To test another mode, empty the db table (`customer`) to have a clean one.

---

**BENCHMARKING**

INSERT
Creating 10 000 objects (not measured) and inserting them into database.

- No data: ~26-27 seconds
  [image]
- Primitives: ~27.1-27.4 seconds
  [image]
- Prim + one complex: ~27.5-29 seconds
  [image]
- Full data: ~28 seconds
  [image]

*So, all in all, around the same, 26-29 seconds.*

SELECT
Reading 10 000 objects from db, as inserted above.

- No data: ~460 ms
  [image]
- Primitives: ~700-720 ms
  [image]
- Prim + one complex: ~970-1030 ms
  [image]
- Full data: 30000-32000 ms (30-32 seconds)
  [image]

**CONCLUSIONS**

"Full data" is obviously where the big smack-in-the-face appears. 
The complex blobbed objects that is added (`ContactDetails`), seems to mess it up. I noticed this in a previous test, but the object itself isn't very complex, see below. So, I am not sure why it jumps like this, or if these numbers are reasonable.

I had asked a previous question about this, but this benchmarking should be more accurate.

The question is: why does persisting an object (to JSON as per OrmLite) slow down SELECTs in this way?

```html
[Serializable]
public class ContactDetails 
{
    public List<ContactItem> ContactItemList
    {
        get; set;
    }
    public ContactItem CurrentContactItem
    {
        get; set; 
    }
    public ContactItem DefaultContactItem
    {
        get; set;
    }
    public bool IgnorePrimaryWaitBuffer
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public ContactDetails(List<ContactItem> contactItemList, ContactItem currentContactItem, ContactItem defaultContactItem)
    {
        ContactItemList = contactItemList;
        CurrentContactItem = currentContactItem;
        DefaultContactItem = defaultContactItem;
    }

    public ContactDetails()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Your project still has references to `..\..\..\..\[GIT]\Alfa\Server`. If you're going to put together a benchmark for others to look at, make it standalone project and include all the sources, i.e. don't reference compiled .dll's no-one else can debug. You should also include `Tracer.Instance = new ConsoleTracer();` to see if the serializer is logging any serialization errors to the console.

Comment: I dont see any references too Alfa/Server in the two projects `Commons` and `OrmLiteTests` (the only two projects now included in the .sln...) So I consider it standalone, since all sources that I control are there (the classes are all included in the Commons project).
Where do you see that reference exactly?

Comment: I updated the GitHub repo (removed unused project that wasnt included in the .sln file, added Tracer and fixed one weird NullRef that didnt happen before). Im not sure how to use the Tracer.Instance, but I did create it and I see no errors anywhere. Loading times for the "Full data" is still 29 seconds.

Comment: @mythz ? I cant see any ref to Alfa\Server, the project is clean an runnable as I can see it. Before posting, I downloaded what I put on GitHub as a ZIP file and ran it from a new location on disk, and that worked. So, I think its standalone. I would really like some input on the slow SELECT there =)

Comment: Thanks for making the project workable, I've managed to profile it and find/resolve the issue which is available from v5.1.1 on MyGet. You'll need to clear your NuGet package cache (i.e. with `nuget locals all -clear`) to download the latest v5.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to download and profile this solution which highlighted the cause of the issue of not caching the type accessors of late-bound types which is resolved with [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/commit/2404683865ccefdb68a6d18bbc04b9ca368fec92).

With this change performance for loading 10000 rows with complex types reduced from 11,765ms to **669ms** (on my iMac 5k) as seen below:

[image]

This change is available from v5.1.1 that's now [available on MyGet](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

Note: I've removed the `JsConfig.IncludeTypeInfo` line below:

```
JsConfig.IncludeTypeInfo = true;
```

Which forces the Serializers to emit type info for every object which [increases the payload size and decreases performance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10759250/85785). ServiceStack.Text will already emit the type info when it's needed, i.e. for `object`, `interfaces` and `abstract` classes, so you should rarely force it yourself unless it's absolutely needed, as it can have a major detrimental impact on performance.

Ideally your DTO's should not use interfaces, late-bound objects or inheritance but if you are consider making the base types `abstract` to force the type info to only where it's needed, instead of always emitting them.

Comment: Thanks for that! I will test it out later today. Regarding `IncludeTypeInfo`: That was necessary for me to add, otherwise the objects wasnt serialized or deserialized correctly. Thats why I added it. The DTOs are inherited; most object oriented code uses inheritance, and we do in our project, extensively. This is not something we can remove or go away from.

Comment: So, after manually clearing the nuget cache, something good happened =) Loading times are now about 1.5 seconds, instead of 30 seconds. The objects seems to be correctly populated in the test-project above. I also tried adding the `JsConfig.IncludeTypeInfo = true;` and even with it, it was 1.5 seconds approximately. In this particular case, it doesnt seem to matter, but I will leave it out until I see that I require it.

Comment: I see now that I already commented in your SO answer where you talk about DTOs and coupling etc. in this case I am serializing and deserializing a `Customer`, but in many many cases I will be serializing the parent object (lets say `Actor` or so). Thats why I needed the IncludeTypeInfo. Well, I'll find out when and how I need it, as my testing goes on. Regarding the INSERT times, do you have any thoughts or comments regarding that? Lookin' good? =)

Comment: @Ted Most of the Insert time is spent in the ADO.NET provider, e.g. creating queries and adding params etc. I've [resolved one perf issue relating to enums](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/bde50b158a57b26bb882d1831860770e7107d3e0) (now on v5.1.1) but otherwise most time is spent in the ADO.NET provider not the serializer. You can increase perf by using InsertAll(customers) instead of calling Insert(customer) for each row as it's able to reuse the same parameterized statement which makes it go down to **2638 ms** from **6370 ms** for inserting 10k Full data records.

Comment: Alright, thank you for that input, much appreciated =)